# How can a Spinner have a different style?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I am creating my own theme but I'm having some trouble with one of my Spinners.

I can change all the Spinner style at once, by using `<item name="android:spinnerStyle">`, `<item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">` and `<item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">` in the theme, but I can't find a way to change one special Spinner that must have a different style.

If I define a new style called SpecialSpinner and add `style="@style/SpecialSpinner"` to the Spinner definition in the layout, I can modify the Spinner itself, but how can I modify this Spinner's spinnerItem and spinnerDromDownItem?

Comment: I have also passed from this situation. So I have used the Custom Alert Dialog with inflating the ListView in AlertDialog.. Do you need some code idea..?

Comment: Spinner is the one of the Bad Ui control in android.

Comment: I can't create a custom adapter, it's too difficult because I'm using the same spinner somewhere else. The only thing that changes is the text shown on the Spinner.

Comment: Same here.. I want to display the different color of the during popup of spineer and different color after selection.